# ERROR org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator - failed to turn code into token

Tags: nginx, single-sign-on, keycloak, http-status-code-403

We have a problem with our application, Nginx and keycloak. There are 3 instances: instance 1 APP, Instance 2 NGINX (reverse proxy) and Instance 3 Keycloak.

When a user logs in, he creates the session in keycloak but when he returns to the SiAe application it is when he returns 403.
We enter the keycloak administration console and see that the session was successful and is open. But it is not possible that the return to the application works.

### Logs

#### Nginx:

```
    "GET /opensat/?state=dcc1c40f-3183-4c7b-8342-f7df620cf0b3&session_state=605ba79a-ee05-4918-a96d-71466e31210a&code=fe066a17-a97a-495c-94f9-b1e5e3d6ac1f.605ba79a-ee05-4918-a96d-71466e31210a.f91920a4-3267-4de5-9788-24093a32c217 HTTP/1.1" **403 405** "https://mydomain/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"
```

#### APP:

```
ERROR org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator  - failed to turn code into token
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:573)
        at org.keycloak.adapters.SniSSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SniSSLSocketFactory.java:114)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:557)
        at org.keycloak.adapters.SniSSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SniSSLSocketFactory.java:109)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
```

#### Keycloak:

`**INFO**  [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPIdentityStoreRegistry] (default task-1) Creating new LDAP Store for the LDAP storage provider: 'ldap_pre', LDAP Configuration: {pagination=[true], fullSyncPeriod=[-1], usersDn=[ou=usuarios,dc=domain,dc=es], connectionPooling=[true], cachePolicy=[DEFAULT], useKerberosForPasswordAuthentication=[false], importEnabled=[true], enabled=[true], changedSyncPeriod=[86400], bindDn=[cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=es], usernameLDAPAttribute=[uid], lastSync=[1575269470], vendor=[other], uuidLDAPAttribute=[entryUUID], connectionUrl=[ldap://MIIP:389], allowKerberosAuthentication=[false], syncRegistrations=[false], authType=[simple], debug=[false], searchScope=[1], useTruststoreSpi=[ldapsOnly], priority=[0], userObjectClasses=[inetOrgPerson, organizationalPerson, person], rdnLDAPAttribute=[cn], editMode=[WRITABLE], validatePasswordPolicy=[false], batchSizeForSync=[1000]}, binaryAttributes: []`

### Configurations:

#### Nginx:

```
location / {

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://IP_KEYCLOAK:8081;
}
```

#### Keycloak:

```
     ....
        <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="proxyhttps" proxy-address-forwarding="true" enable-http2="true"/>
     ......
             <socket-binding name="proxy-https" port="443"/>
     .....
```

#### APP .json:

```
{
  "realm": "domain",
  "auth-server-url": "https://domainkeycloak/",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "sso",
  "enable-cors" : true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "98236f9a-c8b1-488c-8b36-ace4f95b1aa6"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "disable-trust-manager":true,
  "allow-any-hostname" : true
}
```

Could anybody help us, please?

Comment: does the Exception in your APP offer a longer stracktrace (e.g. more information, a `CAUSED BY` maybe?) - it seems like there is an issue when the app tries to connect to keycloak to exchange the temporary key with an access_token

Comment: No it doesn't.
Ends as follows:
.....
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2019-12-23 14:29:24,811 localhost-startStop-2 ERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution** has been to separate keycloak with other Nginx instead of using one Nginx for APP and Keycloak. Now, we have 2 Nginx's and run OK keycloak with our APP.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Connection reset` means that the application cannot make request to Keycloak server. You should investigate the issue further by logging in to the application server and telnet keycloak domain with 443 port since you set `auth-server-url` to `https://domainkeycloak/`

Comment: Hello!, 
Thanks for your reply, but the configuration auth-server-url is OK:

`"auth-server-url": "https://midomain.com/auth"`

We have the same configuration on-premise and It run OK, but this configuration on AWS doesn't run.